# How can I show custom tax , shipping Charge and Discount data in Stripe checkout session

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am implementing the Stripe payment gateway using the Stripe checkout session. I want to show the custom tax, shipping charge, and discount on the Stripe checkout page. How can I achieve that?

```
        $checkout_session = Session::create([
        'line_items'    => $lineItems, 
        'metadata'      => ['payment_type'  => 'stripe','order_id' => $orderID],
        'mode'          => 'payment',
        'success_url'   => $stripeConstants->getSuccessUrl($orderID),
        'cancel_url'    => $stripeConstants->getCancelUrl($orderID),
        'payment_intent_data' => [
            'metadata' => ['order_id' => $orderID],
        ],
    ]);
```

This is my code. How can I add those additional information? Custom tax, shipping charge, and discount.

Answer (score 0):

These are the guides for each feature on Checkout Session:

- Automatic tax: https://stripe.com/docs/tax/checkout
- Shipping rate: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/during-payment/charge-shipping?payment-ui=checkout&dashboard-or-api=api
- Discounts: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/discounts

Comment: I already saw those guides. but I do not want to create any tax, shipping, or discount coupons on the Stripe end. I already have those value that is tax, shipping, and discount amount. just want to show them on Stripe checkout.

Answer (score 0):

I only found how to show shipping Charge in Stripe checkout session but i am using nextJS in fontend and wordpress as backend:

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    line_items,
    shippingOptions = [
        {
            shipping_rate_data: {
                type: "fixed_amount",
                fixed_amount: {
                    amount: Math.round(shipping_metod.total * 100),
                    currency: "EUR",
                },
                display_name: shipping_metod.method_title,
            },
        },
    ],
    mode: "payment",
    payment_method_types: ["card", "sepa_debit"],
    success_url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL}/cart?success=1`,
    cancel_url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL}/cart?canceled=1`,
    metadata: {
      orderId: order.id,
    },
});
```